# BigQuery Sink Connector - Auto create table gives error

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery

I have a BQ Sink connector with the following properties.

```json
{
    "name": "bq-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "mc.dbo.mytbl",
        "autoCreateTables": "true",
        "allowNewBigQueryFields": "true",
        "sanitizeTopics": "true",
        "allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation": "true",
        "autoUpdateSchemas": "true",
        "schemaRetriever": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.retrieve.IdentitySchemaRetriever",
        "project": "myproject-bq",
        "defaultDataset": "cdc_testing_debezium",
        "keyfile": "/opt/bq.json",
        "bufferSize": 10000,
        "maxWriteSize": 1000,
        "tableWriteWait": 100,
        "keySource": "FILE",
        "bigQueryPartitionDecorator": false,
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "bigQueryRetry": 1,
        "transforms": "RegexTransformation",
        "transforms.RegexTransformation.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.RegexTransformation.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.RegexTransformation.replacement": "$4"
    }
}
```

But after deployment, its giving the following error.

```
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: Exception in thread "pool-10-thread-1" com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: Failed to unionizeschemas of records for the table GenericData{classInfo=[datasetId, projectId, tableId], {datasetId=cdc_testing_debezium, tableId=mc_dbo_mytbl}}Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: Caused by: Could not convert to BigQuery schema with a batch of tombstone records.
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.getTableInfo(SchemaManager.java:297)Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.createTable(SchemaManager.java:240)
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.attemptTableCreate(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:161)Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.performWriteRequest(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:102)
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.BigQueryWriter.writeRows(BigQueryWriter.java:112)Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter.run(TableWriter.java:93)
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: Caused by: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: Could not convert to BigQuery schema with a batch of tombstone records.
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.getAndValidateProposedSchema(SchemaManager.java:315)Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.getTableInfo(SchemaManager.java:294)
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: #011... 8 moreJan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: [2023-01-11 04:51:26,332] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=bq-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is beingkilled and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: A write thread has failed with an unrecoverable error (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:608)Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: A write thread has failed with an unrecoverable error
Jan 11 04:51:26 ip-172-31-5-133 connect-distributed[1594]: Caused by: Failed to unionize schemas of records for the table GenericData{classInfo=[datasetId, projectId, tableId], {datasetId=cdc_testing_debezium, tableId=mc_dbo_mytbl}}
```

If I set  `"autoCreateTables": "false"` and  `"autoUpdateSchemas": "false"` and create the table manually, then it works. Not sure how do I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. If we want to use the `AutoCreate Table` and `Auto Update Schema` features, then we must enable the Key and Value converter schemas property.

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```